# How to use custom data base dialect in spring data?

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I need to avoid some bug in db2 dialect in hibernate.
I use spring data + gradle (several modules) + kotlin
I  created my custom dialect

```
DB2zOSDialect : DB2Dialect()
```

And try to add it to application.properties

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: com.my.config.DB2zOSDialect
```

But spring data continuous using DB2Dialect

I tried the same code but using java + maven + the same spring data and it's works.

So, i have no ideas why my custom dialect isn't being use by spring data.

Are there ways how to add dialect to spring data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, i solved problem by my own, but i still don't know why behavior is different.

I set

```
spring.jpa.database = default
```

and added

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect_resolvers = com.my.config.CustomDialectResolver
```

And wrote simple resolver

```
class CustomDialectResolver : DialectResolver {

    override fun resolveDialect(info: DialectResolutionInfo?): Dialect {
        return DB2zOSDialect()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class CustomDialectResolver implements DialectResolver {
    private static final Map<String, Class<? extends Dialect>> DIALECT_BY_NAME = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        DIALECT_BY_NAME.put("Oracle", Oracle10gDialect.class);
        DIALECT_BY_NAME.put("PostgreSQL", PostgreSQL10Dialect.class);
        DIALECT_BY_NAME.put("HSQL Database Engine", HSQLDialect.class);
        DIALECT_BY_NAME.put("H2", H2Dialect.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialect resolveDialect(DialectResolutionInfo dialectResolutionInfo) {
        final String name = dialectResolutionInfo.getDatabaseName();
        return lookupDialect(name);
    }

    private Dialect lookupDialect(String databaseName) {
        Class<? extends Dialect> dialectClass = DIALECT_BY_NAME.get(databaseName);
        if (dialectClass == null) {
            log.warn("Could not find dialect for database name {}", databaseName);
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return dialectClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error while init dialect for database name {} - {}", databaseName, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and next

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect_resolvers=CustomDialectResolver
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining the overall approach / what the code is doing.